# How to get playable link of video file from google drive

Tags: php, laravel, google-drive-api

I'm uploading media files to google drive using drive api v3 with PHP Laravel. I want to get that file playable link to play in my android media app. I'm getting link but that is not playable.

```
$file = $service->get->file($file_id);
```

Comment: Could we remove the **google-apps-script** tag from this? Unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a file ID for your video and have shared it publicly, you can simply get the video on [https://drive.google.com/file/d/**YOUR ID**/preview](https://drive.google.com/file/d/YOURID/preview) .